# Automatic run gulp tasks via npm

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I usually run gulp via npm, e.g. in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test",
    "minify": "gulp minify"
}
```

Then I can run command such as

```
npm run minify
```

Which is okay, but every time I've new tasks in my gulpfile, I need to add them to the package.json under the scripts section, is there any better way to do so?

**Reason**: I only install npm globally to my `path` so all other modules will not pollute my `path`, so I need to run them via `npm` scripts

Comment: Well why are you using `npm run` instead of the normal way? This info could help to know what you really trying to achieve

Comment: I only install npm globally, so npm is in my path, I don't want gulp to pollute my path so I run gulp via npm.

Comment: why don't you run gulp directly?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have I got a treat for you: I went ahead and made you a simple npm module to handle this.

**[gulp-npm-script-sync](https://github.com/austinpray/gulp-npm-script-sync)**

Here is the gist of it:

```
  var file = fs.readFileSync(config.path || 'package.json', 'utf-8');
  var pkg = JSON.parse(file);
  var tasks = gulp.tasks;

  pkg.scripts = pkg.scripts || {};

  Object.keys(tasks).forEach(function (t) {
    pkg.scripts[t] = 'gulp '+tasks[t].name;
  });
```

The [full source](https://github.com/austinpray/gulp-npm-script-sync/blob/master/index.js) does stuff like write the package.json back with the same indention and stuff.

So yeah go ahead: `npm install --save-dev gulp-npm-script-sync`

Stick this in your gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sync = require('gulp-npm-script-sync');

// your gulpfile contents

sync(gulp);
```

Every time you update your gulpfile with a new task it will update your package.json.

You can even throw it inside a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('sync', function () {
  sync(gulp);
}
```

Comment: I think the answer below by Roman is more elegant, and you get away with one less dev dependency.

Comment: I agree. I use `npm run webpack -- --watch` or `npm run webpack -- -d` a lot for instance.

Answer (score 32):

> Brian Brennan gave [a fantastic suggestion](https://twitter.com/brianloveswords/status/501014961058222080): adding
>   **`./node_modules/.bin`** to your `$PATH` variable. **Then you can run locally
>   installed utilities as long as you’re in the top directory of a
>   project.**

Source: [Keeping clean](http://soledadpenades.com/2014/08/22/keeping-clean/).

No need to install a package globally to be able to invoke it easily. Just remember that the above path should be *prepended*.

---

Alternatively, since version 2.0.0, `npm` provides the ability to pass extra parameters to our run commands. These arguments will be simply appended to your script command.

In your case, the following script from your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "gulp"
},
```

can be invoked as `npm run gulp -- test`, or `npm run gulp -- minify`, etc.

Comment: A hint for those who struggle installing `npm@2.0.0` under Windows: execute `npm update npm` from the node.js folder (e.g., `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`). This likely requires administrator rights.

Comment: The beauty of defining the scripts in your manifest is that you create a generic api. `npm run build` could trigger a gulp or a grunt task or anything else. You can change the implementation as your project develops. The interface remains the same and will remain working. You also don't need to add anything to your $PATH in that case, as you could simply do:
`"scripts": { "build": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp build" }`.

Comment: @Jasper Yes, additional levels of indirection can provide benefits. However, usually there is no need to replace a build system, and any indirection also has a cost. Personally, I prefer invoking `gulp` interface directly when it is used in a project, without combining it with anything else or introducing an interface to hide another interface. Same is true for `grunt` and `npm`. Also, I don't like the second option in my answer, it is included just for sharing info. As for the first option, it allows me to avoid installing packages globally, in an elegant and very robust way.